# Kestrel using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate with multiple users

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core, kerberos, asp.net-core-3.1

The Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate documentation says the following [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#windows-environment-configuration) about how to configure Kestrel to use Windows Authentication:

> The Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate component performs
>   User Mode authentication. Service Principal Names (SPNs) must be added
>   to the user account running the service, not the machine account.
>   Execute setspn -S HTTP/myservername.mydomain.com myuser in an
>   administrative command shell.

which works fine. But it does not explain what to do if there are multiple applications that run under different users. If I try to execute `setspn -S HTTP/myservername.mydomain.com myuser; setspn -S HTTP/myservername.mydomain.com myuser2` I get the error `Duplicate SPN found, aborting operation!`.

I tried to use the port when registering the SPN (`setspn -S HTTP/myservername.mydomain.com:5000 myuser`) but that registration seems to be ignored.

Is it not possible to run two asp.net core applications with windows authentication on the same server under different users or do I have to register this differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service principal name must be unique within Active Directory and can only be associated to a single service account.

SPNs are determined based on the hostname they're connecting to, so

`https://foo.bar.com` is equivalent to `https://foo.bar.com:8234/baz`

And for completeness if `foo.bar.com` is a CNAME record, the browser will actually use the canonical A record (e.g. `foo.bar.com` => `srv1-ny-web.corp.bar.net` will use the latter when searching for an SPN).

You have two options: run on separate (sub-)domains or use the same account for both. Using the same account for both is identical to using the machine account. For further similarity use a gMSA account so you don't have to manage the password.

Comment: MSSQL includes the port in its SPN (optionally). Or are you saying that the HTTP service is defined to only use `HTTP/<domain>`? I couldn't find any information how SPNs are determined and how server and client interact there.

Comment: I guess I'll have to look into different domains then, since using a single account for all  applications means that that account would also have access to all databases and other resources the different applications use which is not exactly what I'd want. Having the kernel do the Kerberos authentication with http.sys made that easier.

Comment: How would that make it easier? Running two apps with machine auth is identical to running two apps as a service account security-wise.

Comment: I might be completely wrong here, but my thinking is: With http.sys I can still have 2 separate accounts for the two applications since the Kernel does the authentication. So if one of the applications has an exploitable bug it can't be used to steal information from the database of the other application or write to its files, etc. since it uses a separate account (assuming sensible permissions).

Comment: You're not wrong. My point was just that this is not special to Kestrel. This is just how it works with Kerberos regardless of platform.

Comment: You can use an A record instead of a CNAME, and set the SPN on that, but this comes with the drawback of needing to keep the A record's IP address up to date.
The other option is to use Http.sys instead of Kestrel. Http.sys does the authentication in the kernel, so uses the machine account instead of the service account. In a domain environment, the `HOST/` spn will already be set to the machine account, so there is no need to run `setspn`.